# How to prevent react re-rendering images that are coming from an url?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, redux

This is how my app looks like right now:

[image]

The search and sort functions are working dynamically, as soon as I type a letter, it finds the match but re-renders all of them.

If I type "hunger", it finds the hunger games films, but it's getting images and rendering when it already has them. Is there any way to make this process just for once so I don't wait for every search, every sorting?  I use Redux so data is coming from store, store is getting the data from local json file.

I thought about storing on local storage but I couldn't figure it out. As you can see there is no ComponentDidMount or Hooks.

This is the code of this page:

```js
import React from "react";
import "./MoviesAndSeries.css";
import ListShowItem from "./ListShowItem";
import { getVisibleShows } from "../Redux/Selector";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import FilterShowItems from "./FilterShowItems";
const Movies: React.FC = (props: any) => {
  return (
    <div className="movies">
      <FilterShowItems />
      {props.movies.map((movie: any) => {
        return <ListShowItem key={Math.random()} {...movie} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => {
  return {
    movies: getVisibleShows(state.movies, state.filters),
    filters: state.filters,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Movies);
```

Comment: When you write "getting images" again, do you mean it is requesting images from the server? Shouldn't those images be cached automatically by the browser?

Comment: @terrymorse it looks like it is requesting the images again and again from that url. Otherwise the same picture shouldn't make me wait for it to load. Or is it just a normal thing?

Comment: [According to the React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) Any change to the props triggers an update to be sent down the chain, parent to child, so, your filter changes, which means that the entire component is once again re-rendered. More importantly, where are you passing `props.filters` I do not see it being passed to `FilterShowItems`.

Comment: @İlker You mean network requests? Yeah, they're "requested" but they'll be retrieved from cache, if you are using chrome, take a peek into the network tab to find out more.

Comment: @Xavier I am using Redux so it comes from connect() function.

Comment: @Xavier I mean I think I couldn't describe it well, but these images are coming from an url. And it looks like when I search something , they are being requested again. I was thinking exactly like you, it should come from the cache and should not make me wait after the first load.

Comment: @İlker Ah, so you're also passing `state.filters` from redux directly to `FilterShowItems`? (That is not a good way to pass on props props, as you can directly pass it from this function, but keeping that aside.) 

Ah, no while they're requested from a URL, they're retrieved from cache. [An example](https://i.imgur.com/jZMkwPz.png) They're "retrieved" from the URL, but their actual request is sent to the cache

Comment: @Xavier so is this behaviour normal? I still don't get it. If I deploy this to netlify or something would you take a look ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `Math.random()` as keys. The keys change all the time, and React can't know if the items already exist, so it re-renders all of them:

```
<ListShowItem key={Math.random()} {...movie} />;
```

Change the key to something stable, and unique, the movie `id` (if you have one) for example:

```
<ListShowItem key={movie.id} {...movie} />;
```

Comment: Hi, I changed it to "React.Children.toArray" later. it does the same thing. Should I give specific IDs still ?

Comment: Yes, you should. The key should be unique and stable, and you don't need `React.Children.toArray`.

Comment: Okay last question, I just gave the index coming from map function, key. It is still doing same thing while that index is stable? So I should still define a id  property ? Is this why they're saying assigning index as a key, a bad thing?

Comment: Yes, because when you filter the array, the index of each item changes, so it's not stable. Add an `id` or use a combination of the movie name, and data of release, etc...

Comment: Thank you very much, it is pretty much solved. Sorting is working instantly and search also, as expected. But, when I delete the search word, it renders again. So if I write "hun" hunger games films are displayed instantly, but when I delete, it renders. If it's normal, I'll just leave it like this.

Comment: This sounds like a problem. Check what happens to the movies array.
Not related, but you can optimize a bit more by hiding instead of removing. Add hidden property to the movie object, and show/hide (`display: none`) accordingly.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much man. Really you saved my day, so if anyone comes here and tries to find answer, I pushed the indexes of every object in the array, as a property. So each object has id property equals to its index. Now it's exactly what I desired. Very much appreciated.